# Search for a value by class or repeater in protractor?

Tags: class, protractor, repeater

I have a table with multiple columns and multiple rows, the rows are in repeater and each row has the same class. Basically I am automating a search functionality test in protractor and I want to see if the searched value is present in the results that are given. So basically I need to go inside each class or repeater visible and check for a value? If the value is present or contained in any of the elements the test passes, if not the test fails.

Comment: What exactly are you asking/need help with?  Can you give an example, show some code?  Yes you can search by either [repeater](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater) or [class/css](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.css)

Comment: This is a very vague question.  I recommend coming back with a specific problem after you've attempted to code a solution.

Comment: Edited the post @Gunderson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your search string is "SearchKey" and results are displayed in a list of elements like below

```
<li class="file" ng-repeat="result in results" ng-class="{blahblah}">
<li class="file" ng-repeat="result in results" ng-class="{blahblah}">
<li class="file" ng-repeat="result in results" ng-class="{blahblah}">
```

Your test case should have assertion something like below

```
        var xpathExp = "//li[contains(.,'" + SearchKey + "')]"
        expect(element(by.xpath(xpathExp).isDisplayed()).to.eventually.be.true;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking what locator to choose - "by repeater" or a "by class", generally speaking, *the choice would depend on how distinct and readable of a repeater and class you have available.*

For instance, if you have `item in items` repeater and `product` class, it would be preferred to use the `product` class since `item in items` is too generic of a repeater and might not be distinct on the page at the moment or in the future (this might come as a surprise some day and might lead to some hair loss during debugging).

Or the opposite example, if you have `product in products` repeater and `col-md-1` class, then the "by repeater" locator would be preferred since `col-md-1` class is a UI- and layout- oriented class and does not contain or bring any "data"-specific information; and it is more likely to be changed in the future.

---

Another point is that the *"by repeater" locator would make your tests even more tied to AngularJS*, but the "by class" approach is a little bit more generic and is agnostic of what the application is built on.